# How to solve this vector equation including magnitudes?

Tags: vectors

All **boldface** variables are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and K is in $\mathbb{R}$. ${\bf v_1}$ is the only unknown that I want to solve for. All other variables are known. I know this type of thing might typically be approached with a numerical solver, but I'm asking if it can be solved analytically.

$$\|{\bf v_1} - {\bf v_0}\| ({\bf v_0} + {\bf v_1}) + \|{\bf v_2} - {\bf v_1}\| ({\bf v_1} + {\bf v_2}) = 2 K ({\bf p_2} - {\bf p_0})$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use things like $\|{\bf v_1} - {\bf v_0}\| ({\bf v_0} + {\bf v_1})=\sqrt{\|{\bf v_1}\|^2-2{\bf v_1} \cdot {\bf v_0}+\|{\bf v_0}\|^2}({\bf v_0} + {\bf v_1})$ and then exand by components.  You will get three coupled equations that are a mess.  It is probably better to solve it numerically with a minimizer, minimizing on the error of your equation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all the terms are vectors. I don't know if there is a way to solve that directly. However, it can be converted to a scalar equation by in effect "squaring" both sides. This will result in the terms having vector dot products in them which are scalar. Then the equation can be solved through normal equation solving strategies.